# Showing a system of equations has no integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

I am having trouble finding an elegant way of showing this system of equations has no integer solutions:

$$32c+11d=9a+10b$$

$$2c+d=a$$

$$ad-bc=1$$

So far I've narrowed it down to showing $221c^2+100$ cannot be a perfect square, but I'm hoping there's a way that's less computational!

Comment: Why do you expect an easy solution ? We have $4$ unknowns, only $3$ equations, and the last one has degree$2$. I think, you got already very far. Could you finish the proof, or do you need help with the last step ?

Comment: If you could help with that last bit, that would be great! I thought maybe modular arithmetic would help but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: $$221\cdot 5^2+100=75^2$$ What exactly is the equation you got ?

Comment: The equation you get by eliminating $a, d$ is $25b^2 - 61bc +35c^2 = 1$. The quadratic form has discriminant $221$, so it gives what OP writes + some divisibility conditions.

Comment: @user404920 If you show exactly at which equation you arrived, I think we can finish the proof.

Comment: I got $5d^2+9cd-7c^2-5=0$, if I continue with $c=5$ I do get the contradiction that $5b=7c+d$ can't work, but if this expression can be a perfect square I suppose another approach is needed.

My working was: 
$7c+d=5b$ from the first two, then 
$(2c+d)d-\frac{1}{5}(7c+d)c=1$
and then this turns into the aforementioned quadratic

Comment: Maybe, it helps that we know that $c$ and $d$ must be coprime.

Comment: It is $221c^2 + 100 = (50b-61c)^2$

Comment: If we consider the system moduo $5$, we can conclude $5\mid a$. Do you have any result contradicting to this ? If we can show that $221c^2+100$ can only be a perfect square, if $5\mid c$ , we would get the desired contradiction, right ?

Comment: @Peter Right, you mean that when $c = 5 c'$ it gives the contradiction $c'^2 +4 \equiv c'^2 \pmod 5$. If true, it should be easy to check that $5 \mid c$. Are there online tools that compute all primitive solutions? Does Sage do this? Fundamental element of norm $1$ is $\left( (15 + \sqrt{221})/2 \right)^2 < 223$, https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/2.2.221.1

Comment: I meant that $5\mid a$ and $5\mid c$ contradicts that $a$ and $c$ must be coprime. But I do not know how we can find all solutions to such pell-like equations. Dario Alpern programmed a nice tool but I found out that it can occasionally fail. But you can try it out on his site "alpertron". There is an option for a step-by-step solution. I do not know a program that solves a generic equation of this kind fully reliable. I asked for such a program, but did not get a satisfactoring answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems not to be easy to show this. Perhaps, we can show by replacing $c$ by $5k+1,5k+2,5k+3,5k+4$ that none of this possibilities gives a solution. If we knew ALL fundamental solutions , we could perhaps show it more easily, but I do not know a reliable method to do this.

Comment: @Peter pari/gp can get all solutions from modulo polynomial as $n\cdot u^j$, where $n$ is norm (fundamental solution), $u$ is fundamental unit and $j\in \mathbb{N}$ using `bnfinit` and `bnfisintnorm`.

Comment: @Peter I mean, regardless of $a$, when $c = 5 c'$ then dividing by $25$ in $221c^2 + 100 = (50b-61c)^2$ and looking mod $5$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: @BartMichels  the indefinite form $25 x^2 - 61xy+ 35 y^2$  integrally represents $-1$ but not $1$ itself. This is the same information as the fact that $x^2 - 221 y^2$ does not integrally represent $-1,$ which you can confirm using the continued fraction for $\sqrt {221}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADDED: pretty much everything needed for this answer is in this chapter of [BUELL](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/indefinite_binary_Buell.pdf)

[image]

The method suggested in comments gives first $a = d + 2c$  and then $d = 5b-7c.$ Plugging those into $ad-bc=1$ gives
$$  25 b^2 - 61bc + 35 c^2 = 1.  $$
If we had $b=c = 1$  the quadratic form would evaluate to $-1.$ However, $1$ itself is impossible. The printout below shows the Gauss-Lagrange method of "reduced" indefinite binary quadratic forms. It is a theorem of Lagrange that all small numbers (below $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt {221}$ in absolute value) that are **primitively** integrally represented by $\langle 25 -61, 35 \rangle$ must appear as first or last coefficients of a form in the chain of reduced forms equivalent to the original; however

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle  25 -61 35

  0  form             25         -61          35  delta     -1
  1  form             35          -9          -1  delta     -2
  2  form             -1          13          13


          -1           2
          -1           1

To Return  
           1          -2
           1          -1

0  form   -1 13 13   delta  1     ambiguous  
1  form   13 13 -1   delta  -13     ambiguous  
2  form   -1 13 13


  form   -1 x^2  + 13 x y  13 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = 0 disc 221 dSqrt 14  M_Ratio  196
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-1  13
1  -14
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

This is equivalent to the fact that $x^2 - 221 y^2 \neq -1$ for integers $x,y,$ proof by continued fractions, really:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 221
Tue Jun 30 15:05:16 PDT 2020


0  form   1 28 -25   delta  -1
1  form   -25 22 4   delta  6
2  form   4 26 -13   delta  -2
3  form   -13 26 4   delta  6
4  form   4 22 -25   delta  -1
5  form   -25 28 1   delta  28
6  form   1 28 -25

 disc 884
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
97  2800
112  3233


 Pell automorph 
1665  24752
112  1665

Pell unit 
1665^2 - 221 * 112^2 = 1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
15^2 - 221 * 1^2 = 4 

=========================================

221      13 *  17

Tue Jun 30 15:05:16 PDT 2020
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had this idea yesterday because I knew the period length of the continued fraction expansion of sqrt{221} is of even length, so the negative Pell equation has no solution, but I had no idea how to translate that to this question, so once again, thanks! :)

Comment: @user404920 the "chain" method is the cleanest way to draw such conclusions, it is just a slight modification of continued fractions, and uses only integer arithmetic, ever. It is discussed in the Buell chapter in full; also in the 1929 book of Dickson, the one I pasted in with the Lagrange theorem above.

Answer (score 1):

By eliminating $a,d$ we get equation $$25 b^2 - 61 b c + 35 c^2=1\tag{1}$$

Solve $(1)$ by modulo $5$ we get $5\not\mid c$, ([WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25b%5E2-61bc%2B35c%5E2%3D1+mod+5)).

$(1)\implies (50 b - 61 c)^2 - 221 c^2 = 100\overset{50 b - 61 c\to X}{\implies}$

$$X^2-221c=100\tag{2}$$

All solutions of Pell equation $(2)$ we get from modulo polynomial $n\cdot u^j$, where $n$ is norm (fundamental solution), $u$ is fundamental unit and $j\in\mathbb{N}$.

For $(2)$ we have $n=10$ and $u\equiv(x-15)/2\pmod{x^2-221}$.

Example:

$10\cdot\Bigl((x-15)/2\Bigr)^{7}\pmod{x^2-221}\equiv 55694245x - 827954475\pmod{x^2-221}$,

i.e. $(X,c)=(827954475,55694245)$.

gp-code: `10*Mod((x-15)/2, x^2-221)^7`=`Mod(55694245*x - 827954475, x^2 - 221)`.

Solving $(2)$ in pari/gp:

```
abcd()=
{
 D= 221; C= 100;
 Q= bnfinit('x^2-D, 1);
 fu= Q.fu[1]; print("Fundamental Unit: "fu);
 N= bnfisintnorm(Q, C); print("Fundamental Solutions (Norm): "N"\n");
 for(i=1, #N, ni= N[i];
  for(j=0, 16,
   s= lift(ni*fu^j);
   X= abs(polcoeff(s, 0)); Y= abs(polcoeff(s, 1));  
   if(Y, if(X^2-D*Y^2==C,
    print("("X", "Y")    j="j)
   ))
  )
 )
};
```

Output:

```
? abcd()
Fundamental Unit: Mod(1/2*x - 15/2, x^2 - 221)
Fundamental Solutions (Norm): [10]

(75, 5)    j=1
(1115, 75)    j=2
(16650, 1120)    j=3
(248635, 16725)    j=4
(3712875, 249755)    j=5
(55444490, 3729600)    j=6
(827954475, 55694245)    j=7
(12363872635, 831684075)    j=8
(184630135050, 12419566880)    j=9
(2757088153115, 185461819125)    j=10
(41171692161675, 2769507719995)    j=11
(614818294272010, 41357153980800)    j=12
(9181102721918475, 617587801992005)    j=13
(137101722534505115, 9222459875899275)    j=14
(2047344735295658250, 137719310336497120)    j=15
(30573069306900368635, 2056567195171557525)    j=16
```

In fine, because for $(2)$ norm $=10$, then $5\mid c$ for $(2)$. But this contradiction with $5\not\mid c$ for $(1)$.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! This question came from a book I'm reading that said something along the lines of: "the reader can easily check for themselves there is no integer solution"... I guess what is easy is subjective!

Answer (score 0):

It is not true because $(a,b,c,d)=(0,-1,-1,2)$ is an integer solutions as it is easily verified.

►$32c+11d=9a+10b$ has a solution $(a,d)=(5b+6c+11n,5b+2c+9n)$ where $n\in\mathbb Z$

►Therefore $2c+d=a$ gives $c=-n$

►It follows $ad-bc=1$ gives $25b^2+59bn+35n^2=1$ which admits the solution $(b,n)=(-1,1),(1,-1)$ from which the above counterexample $(a,b,c,d)=(0,-1,-1,2)$.

Comment: There are a mistake because instead of $60bn-bn$ it sould be $60bn+bn$. I am sorry.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but ad - bc = -1 in your counterexample?

Comment: Non, you are right. I have made a mistake in this and I have apologized for it. If you prefer. I could delete my answer, I did not it because of showing the two first parts, mainly the first one (sorry by the very bad English).